# Django save user and profile with signals

Tags: python, django, signals, profile

Im still learning Django and I am stuck at user registration / profile creation.

**My goal**

So, the purpose of this is to save the new user and at the same time save the profile of the new user with de data from the form. I use 2 forms u_form and p_form.

**What I have done so far:**

- Created model Profile with OneToOneField to User
- Created 2 forms for User (u_form) and Profile (p_form)
- Created signals.py to create new Profile when new User is created
- In the view I have create function with u_form.save()

**Problem**

This works, but the new Profile is completely empty.. When I put p_form.save() in my view it gives me this error:

NOT NULL constraint failed

**The code**

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voorletter = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    voorvoegsel = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    achternaam = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    depers = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    depersoud = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    telefoonnummer = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Collega"
        verbose_name_plural = "Collega's"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.depers
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from gebruikers.forms import UserRegisterForm, ProfileRegisterForm

def gebruiker_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        p_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account is aangemaakt.')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        u_form = UserRegisterForm()        
        p_form = ProfileRegisterForm()

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password'}), label="Wachtwoord", help_text=None)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password'}), label="Wachtwoord herhalen", help_text=None)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class ProfileRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    voorletters = forms.CharField(label="Voorletters", max_length=10)
    voorvoegsel = forms.CharField(label="Voorvoegsel", max_length=50)
    achternaam = forms.CharField(label='Achternaam', max_length=100)
    depers = forms.CharField(label='Depers', max_length=8)
    depersoud = forms.CharField(label='Oude Depers', max_length=50)
    telnummer = forms.CharField(label="Telefoonnummer", max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['voorletters', 'voorvoegsel', 'achternaam', 'depers', 'depersoud', 'telnummer']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Profile fields to be empty initially just add `blank=True` in every model fields except for user .

```
voorletter = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
.....
.....
.....
telefoonnummer = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
```

Then run makemigrations and migrate command to successfully make the changes in the database.

it will solve NOT NULL constraint failed error

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Problem is it gives the NOT NULL constraint failure on the user_id